# ffmpeg : setting a rectangle in a video to black

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I want to set a rectangle in a video to black, so that each frame in the video will have this black rectangle.
Is it possible ?

I want something similar to this:
"[How to put border around video to prevent clipping of content](https://superuser.com/questions/869117/how-to-put-border-around-video-to-prevent-clipping-of-content)" but instead of a black border I want a black rectangle
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNC6f.png)

Comment: You can check this Q/A: https://superuser.com/questions/869117/how-to-put-border-around-video-to-prevent-clipping-of-content

Comment: Ok, looking at the duck example I was able to do what I want: `./ffmpeg -y -i sample.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=30x40 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=w=iw:h=ih[scaled]; [0:v][scaled]overlay=x=0.20*main_w:y=0.10*main_h:eof_action=endall[out]; [0:a]anull[aud]" -map "[out]" -map "[aud]" -strict -2 outputfile.mp4`

Comment: In such case you can answer your own question :)

Answer (score 22):

Ok, looking at the duck example I was able to do what I want:

```
./ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=30x40 \
-filter_complex "[1:v]scale=w=iw:h=ih[scaled]; \
[0:v][scaled]overlay=x=0.20*main_w:y=0.10*main_h:eof_action=‌​endall[out]; \
[0:a]anull[aud]" -map "[out]" -map "[aud]" -strict -2 out.mp4
```

this puts a 30X40 rectangle on the video.

also "drawbox" works:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 \
-vf "drawbox=x=10:y=10:w=100:h=100:color=pink@0.5:t=fill" out.mp4
```

Comment: I found the drawbox example easier to understand. At some point after your answer, an update to ffmpeg now mandates that you replace `t=max` with `t=fill`. I'll go ahead and update your answer to reflect this.

Comment: rest of parameters: `@0.5` is alpha/transparency channel (0.0-transparent, 1.0 opaque), `t=fill` -- thickness of the box edge, `fill` means filled box. Source: `man ffmpeg-filters` or https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox